# Django Rest Framework with UTF-8

Tags: python, django, utf-8, django-rest-framework

I am using  Django `1.10` and Django Rest Framework `3`.
Here is my view of`GET` method(list):

```
class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):


def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
    content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
    super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


@csrf_exempt
def news_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        news = News.objects.all()
        serializer = Newsserializer(news, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

Well it works just fine and gives me all my rows in `Json` format.

Now i want to use `UTF-8` characters in my columns. But when i `GET` all my data i see characters like this `â˜…` or `Ø´Ø³ÛŒØ¨Ø¨ÛŒÛŒØ¨ÛŒØ³Ø¨`.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you set the `UNICODE_JSON` in your seting? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#unicode-json-by-default

Comment: it fixes the `Ø´Ø³ÛŒØ¨Ø¨ÛŒÛŒØ¨ÛŒØ³Ø¨` but now it looks like this :`\u0634\u0633\u06cc\u0628\u0628\u06cc\u06cc\`. what should i do know ? @kkasramvd

Comment: So that's it. Now you have your unicode string with it's standard representation, you can use a proper encoding to see your expected representation. Although python std-out's default encoding is `utf8` and will show you the decoded sting. And if you want to represent the string in another console you might have to specify the encoding manually.

Comment: If you are using python2.X and your final stdout is python shell or an unix-based terminal do this : `print unicode(s, 'unicode-escape')`. Otherwise  you need to decode the string `s.decode('utf8')`.

Comment: @kasramvd thanks for replays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kasramvd, this problem will solve by setting `UNICODE_JSON` to `Ture` in the setting. the characters will be Unicode like `\u06cc`. then:

```
s.decode('utf8')
```

will solve the problem.
also read about `UNICODE_JSON` [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#unicode_json).

Comment: The default is `True` anyway.